# removing index.php from url of codeigniter installation on DirectAdmin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use .htaccess on my codeigniter installation to remove index.php from the URL, I am using mod_rewrite.

However, its not working, I have placed the .htaccess file on the root directory of my codeigniter installation folder(where application and system folders are located).
DirectAdmin 1.44.3 (on Apache 2.2.26).

My .htaccess file as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|application/views/|robots\.txt|install|favicon\.ico|documents)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php


#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
     # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

How exactly I should remove the index.php on DirectAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try This:**
Remove index.php from application/config/config.php then save it.
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

change in **config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

then use the following **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```